# How do I run Angular.JS 2 for TypeScript on C9.io on port 8080?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, port, c9.io

I followed this quick tutorial: 
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart and build the code on C9.io, but by default it's trying to run on port 3000, and C9.io only allows using ports 8080, 8081, and 8082. So how can I run it on C9.io?

Here's my code: https://ide.c9.io/mathieu_roy/angular2-quickstart

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with the same issue, instead of creating a bs-config.json which will be discoverable automatically you can create a bs-config.js which will also be discoverable by default and be used. Place the bs-config.js file in the root directory.

```
//bs-config.js
module.exports = {
    port: process.env.PORT,
        files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
        server: {
        baseDir: "./"
   }
};
```

now you can use c9 environment variables like process.env.PORT

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `lite` npm script to invoke `lite-server` with a custom configuration including port.

```
{
  "port": 8000,
  "files": ["./src/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}"],
  "server": { "baseDir": "./src" }
}
```

## More

https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server#custom-configuration

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working for some reasons. I added a link to my code above.