# How to configure lite-server port for heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, angular, deployment, lite-server

I am trying to deploy nodejs lite-server on Heroku. I am able to run the server fine locally, but fails on deployment with this error:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

The basic problem is I am not sure how to allow Heroku to set the port. They do this dynamically (I only know how to do it statically). So I need to set an environmental variable so the server can set the correct port. How can I do this using lite-server?

This problem has been address for different server setups:

To configure http server port for Heroku

[Heroku + node.js error (Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of)

To configure Express server port for Heroku

[Heroku Node.js Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092538/heroku-node-js-error-r10-boot-timeout-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-w)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I had the same issue. I ended up adding a bs-config.js file.

```
module.exports = {
    port: process.env.PORT,
    files: ['./**/*.{html,htm,css,js}'],
    server:{
        baseDir: "./"
    }
};
```

Apparently Heroku dynamically assigns a new port each time it's started. So the port can't be hard coded.

[How do I run Angular.JS 2 for TypeScript on C9.io on port 8080?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104588/how-do-i-run-angular-js-2-for-typescript-on-c9-io-on-port-8080/40227463#40227463)

Comment: Thanks, one note though, this is actually a .js script to get the port dynamically on Heroku  a .json file can be used only with a static port since the port number would be hard coded.