# How to run lite-server app on AWS elastic beanstalk?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I've built my node project off of a truffle tutorial here: https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorial. The project is run by running npm start with this in the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "lite-server"
}
```

Now however I'd like to upload my app to AWS ElasticBeanstalk, and it seems like lite-server doesn't work there. Is there a command I can put in here that works instead? I need to run my index.html file which is loads in a script with `<script src="js/app.js"></script>`.

Note: I saw a sample node project that works with AWS ElasticBeanstalk with a package.json that has `"start": "node app.js"`, but that won't work for me because it looks like while their app.js loads the index.html, I have it the other way around. I believe that lite-server doesn't work because when I took this sample project and swapped the start to `"lite-server"`, it stopped working as well. (it works locally though)

Comment: there isn't an exact tutorial/guide available with `lite-server`, but AWS offers several tutorials with `Express` and other `NodeJS` tutorials here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html

Comment: Thanks. I actually fixed it by replacing my bs-config.json with the bs-config.js suggested in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064822/how-to-configure-lite-server-port-for-heroku